# Выбор всех .mp3 файлов из папки

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется метод который позволяет выбрать путь (localpath) до папки с музыкой, однако, если пытаюсь вставить localpath в ***directory = new File(localpath);*** выдаёт ошибки:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.RuntimeException

java.lang.NullPointerException

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователь указывал путь до папки с музыкой, в **Initialize** передавался путь и программа собирала все треки, а затем воспроизводила их.

```java
public void getPath() {
        try {
            Stage stage = (Stage) pane.getScene().getWindow();
            DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
            directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("music"));
            File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);
            localpath = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(localpath);
            currentPath.setText("Current path: " + localpath);
        } catch(java.lang.RuntimeException exc) {showAlert();}
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        songs = new ArrayList<File>();
        directory = new File("music");
        files = directory.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                songs.add(file);

            }
        }


        media = new Media(songs.get(songNumber).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а где строка `directory = new File(localpath)`? Насчёт ошибок, т.е. у Вас после одного исключения ещё два выбрасываются?

Comment: Эта строка  directory = new File("music");, просто не указал это, а касаемо ошибок да, всё верно выбрасываются ещё 2.

Comment: Ну так а что в исключениях-то написано?

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться apache commons

```
File directory = new File("music");
files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(directory , {"mp3","wav"}, true)
```

[Подробнее здесь](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles-java.io.File-java.lang.String:A-boolean-)

Comment: Но мне нужно чтобы я в методе getPath получал путь, который записывается в localpath, а далее было нечто похожее на File directory = new File(***localpath***);, однако если так сделать то программа выдаст ошибку. Проще говоря, как это должно выглядеть, пользователь нажимает кнопку, выбирает путь, который записывается в переменную, в следующей функции из этого пути читаются все mp3 файлы, затем начинается воспроизведение. Я знаю как сделать всё, кроме того чтобы программа читала файлы из любой папки вне проекта папки проекта.